# How can Cosmos DB guarantee similar availability as eventual consistency for strong consistent account?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Cosmos DB documentation seems to suggest that if we configure our Strong consistent Cosmos DB account with >= 3 regions, we get similar availability as eventual consistency ([SLAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/high-availability#slas)).

But, according to the CAP theorem how can this be the case. Suppose we have 3 regions, and there is a network partition isolating 1 read region from the remaining two (1 write and 1 read region). If a write requests comes to the write region, there are two options:

1. Fail the request
2. Commit the write to the write region and the reachable read region. The region outside the partition cannot be reached.

If Cosmos DB goes with option 2, then if a read requests were to come to the region that could not be reached, then because Cosmos DB uses local quorum, it will return stale data, which violates the consistency is guarantees.

Therefore, Cosmos DB must fail the write request in the face of network partitions.

Answer (score 2):

This is accomplished by the use of a dynamic quorum over the regions when using 3+ regions. When one of the secondary read regions is impacted by a network partition, the service will remove it from the quorum, allowing writes to commit and replicate to the other online region for an RTO of 0.

Comment: Okay, you removed the secondary read region impacted by the partition from the quorum required for the write to commit. But, it is possible that a read request from a client can come to the partitioned secondary read region, which would return stale data. I suppose to prevent this Cosmos DB must have health monitors that detect network partitions and "disable" regions for reads and remove them from quorum required for writes?

Comment: To add a bit more, availability at least theoretically is still worse than eventual, because some clients can also be partitioned from regions remaining "enabled". By disabling the secondary read regions to prevent stale reads, and allow writes to succeed, you block access of clients who are also partitioned and can only communicate with the "disabled" secondary read region.

Comment: Partitioned regions will not return read requests, even if the local client can contact the region. This also prevents the second scenario mentioned as the Cosmos SDK client automatically retries reads on the primary region when a secondary does not respond.

Comment: How do you stop the partitioned region from accepting reads? I am just speculating because the network is partitioned, the primary cannot tell the partitioned read region to stop accepting reads. How do you gracefully remove the read region from quorum? I am wanting to know a bit of the internals because I am doubtful that availability is equivalent to session/eventual here.

Answer (score 1):

The primary region periodically gets health signals from all regions that have been created for the account. It also keeps track of the commits that all regions have caught up to. Until the read region that was previously unavailable has caught up to commits it missed out on, it is not marked online. Once fully caught up, it starts accepting new writes from the primary region at steady state and is simultaneously marked available for serving read traffic.

Comment: The health signals stops when there is a network partition. Which would cause the read region to be marked as offline(?), but how exactly is that communicated if there is a network partition? The leader (primary region) cannot coordinate.